# Getting ZoneAwarePromise from Firebase snapshot value

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my component I'm calling a function from a service provider.
Calling a get function from Firebase and what I get in the console is a `ZoneAwarePromise`. What am I doing wrong?

In the `xx.component.ts` file:

```
constructor( private db: Database ) {

    console.log(db.getActiveUserData());

}
```

`database.ts` file:

```
getActiveUserData(){
    return this.database.child('/users/' + this.as.id).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
        return snapshot.val();
    })
}
```

console log:

ZoneAwarePromise
__zone_symbol__state:true

__zone_symbol__value
:
Object
firstname
:
fredrik
uid
:
"zLmRHwQRM0cehsSrGNXaH2WnSgk2"

**proto**
:
Object
**proto**
:
Object

How do I receive the data as a plain object?

When I'm using console log inside the `database.ts`, its all fine

Comment: You can't make realtime, asynchronous operations into synchronous return values. You'll need to use them asynchronously, pass the promise around, and wait for it to resolve (put your console.log() inside the .then(), such as `db.getActiveUserData().then(console.log)`

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the expected behaviour.

`once` returns a promise, so that's what's returned by `getActiveUserData`. You cannot make it return the snapshot's value. However, you can get the returned promise to resolve to the snapshot's value:

```
getActiveUserData() {

  return this.database
    .child('/users/' + this.as.id)
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => snapshot.val());
}
```

Which you'd call like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: "some-component",
    template: `<code>{{ activeUserData | json }}</code>`
})
class SomeComponent {

  activeUserData: any;

  constructor( private db: Database ) {

    db.getActiveUserData().then((val) => { this.activeUserData = val; });
  }
}
```

Angular templates understand promises, so the data could be kept as a promise and the `async` pipe could be used:

```
@Component({
    selector: "some-component",
    template: `<code>{{ activeUserData | async | json }}</code>`
})
class SomeComponent {

  activeUserData: Promise<any>;

  constructor( private db: Database ) {

    this.activeUserData = db.getActiveUserData();
  }
}
```

Comment: That helps! But how do I set the ' val ' to a variable? Like this.activeuser = val.

Comment: I've updated the answer. However, you might want to learn more about promises; there is a lot of material available: [promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org/), [JavaScript Promises: an Introduction](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises)